# php file upload not working returns empty result

Tags: php, html, file, upload

Below is my html code....

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="some.php" method="POST">                           
       <label for="file">Filename:</label>
       <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

and my some.php code...

```
    print_R($_FILES);
    print_r($_POST);
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
       echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Upload: " . $_POST["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
       echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
       echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
       echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    }
```

`$_POST` RESULTS IN `Array ( [file] => gcc-mlion.tar [submit] => Submit )`
BUT `$_FILES` gives empty result.

Comment: `print_R` should be `print_r`

Comment: it is working in my and print array like 
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Programmer- Website Changes.zip
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\phpF829.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 2707463
        )

)
Array
(
    [submit] => Submit
)
Upload: 
Type: application/octet-stream
Size: 2644.00683594 kB
Stored in: D:\xampp\tmp\phpF829.tmp

Please check your apache or .ini settings

Comment: print_R works for me, on the 3 platforms i just tested it

Comment: @Dagon May be `print_R` working , but I think it should not be. May be its a bug in PHP. :)

Comment: its php, there are no bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to output the value of `$_POST['file']['name'];`. It will return an undefined index error message.

Change that line to:

```
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "<br>";
```

That should fix the issue.

Also, here's how I'd do it:

```
<pre>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //checking if form was submitted
{
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_POST);

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) //checking if error'ed
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    }
}
?>
</pre>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">                           
   <label for="file">Filename:</label>
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you try to print File array that time your Spell of "print_r" is wrong.
You write "print_R" instead of "print_r", Php is case sensitive so it's matters a lot.